# "in" operator in linq c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a generic list which contains member details and I have a string array of memberIds..I need to filter the list and get the results which contains all the memberIds..How can I achieve this using LINQ.

I tried the following

```
string[] memberList = hdnSelectedMemberList.Value.Split(',');
_lstFilteredMembers = lstMainMembers.Where(p =>memberList.Contains(p.MemberId))
                                    .ToList();
```

But the above query is giving me only the results that match the first member ID..so lets say if I have memberIds 1,2,3,4 in the memberList array..the result it returns after the query contains only the members with member ID 1..even though the actual list has 1,2,3,4,5 in it..

Can you please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Is `p.MemberId` a string or integer? And is `lstMainMembers` a `List<string>`?

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example including specific inputs, and what output you're expecting?  Thanks.

Comment: lstMainMembers is a list of MemberDetails object which contains the memberName and memberID and the member ID is a string

Comment: I suspect hdnSelectedMemberList doesn't contain the values you think it does. Code looks correct to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings make ***terrible*** primary keys. Try trimming the list:

```
string[] memberList = hdnSelectedMemberList.Value
                          .Split(',')
                          .Select(p => p.Trim())
                          .ToList();

_lstFilteredMembers = lstMainMembers.Where(p => memberList.Contains(p.MemberId)).ToList();
```

Because I have a feeling `hdnSelectedMemberList` may be `"1, 2, 3, 4"`.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the reply..but it is still giving me the same result with the above query too.

Comment: @user788312, try `...Contains(p.MemberId.Trim())`, Also there is no need to call Split method, string is IEnumerable you can do `... hdnSelectedMemberList.Value.Contains(...`

Comment: Joe..you are correct there is a space getting added before every memberID..thanks

Comment: @user788312, first Idea was for Joe second one was for me (saeed:)

Answer (score 1):

Use a join:

```
var memquery = from member in lstMainMembers
               join memberid in memberList 
               on member.MemberId equals memberid
               select member;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Enumerable.Intersect` to get the intersection of two collections:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx

```
_lstFilteredMembers = lstMainMembers.Intersect(memberList.Select(p => p.MemberID.ToString())).ToList()
```

Comment: Nope...lstMainMembers is a list of `Member` objects, not strings. Otherwise that would be nifty.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, updated so that you get a projection of memberlist keys. There are many ways to pull this off with two incompatible lists... the point of the answer is to use Intersect, which seems like what you are really looking for.  Sorry for the bad code sample

Answer (score 0):

Why not just project the IDs list into a list of members?

```
var result = memberList.Select(m => lstMainMembers.SingleOrDefault(mm => mm.MemberId == m))
```

Of course, that will give you a list that contains null entries for items that don't match.

You could filter those out, if you wanted to...

```
result = result.Where(r => r != null)
```

Or you could filter it before the initial select...

```
memberList.Where(m => lstMainMembers.Any(mm => mm.MemberId == m)).Select(m => lstMainMembers.Single(mm => mm.MemberId == m))
```

That's pretty ugly, though.

Answer (score 0):

With jmh, I'd use a join

```
var members = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var ids = new[] { 1, 3, 6, 14 };

var result = members.Join(ids, m => m, id => id, (m, id) => m);

foreach (var r in result)
    Console.WriteLine(r); //prints 1, 3, 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing is correct, and works in a Unit Test:

```
    public class Data
    {
        public string MemberId { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Your_Code_Works()
    {
        // Arrange fake data.
        var hdnSelectedMemberList = "1,2,3,4";
        var lstMainMembers = new[]
            {
                new Data { MemberId = "1" },
                new Data { MemberId = "2" },
                new Data { MemberId = "3" },
                new Data { MemberId = "4" },
                new Data { MemberId = "5" }
            };

        // Act - copy/pasted from StackOverflow
        string[] memberList = hdnSelectedMemberList.Split(',');
        var _lstFilteredMembers = lstMainMembers.Where(p => memberList.Contains(p.MemberId)).ToList();

        // Assert - All pass.
        Assert.AreEqual(4, _lstFilteredMembers.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("1", _lstFilteredMembers[0].MemberId);
        Assert.AreEqual("2", _lstFilteredMembers[1].MemberId);
        Assert.AreEqual("3", _lstFilteredMembers[2].MemberId);
        Assert.AreEqual("4", _lstFilteredMembers[3].MemberId);
    }
```

There must be something wrong with your code outside what you have shown.